# How do I access and change a column in ColumnDataSource in bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I wanted to create a plot with bokeh in python which runs quite well so far. But now I wanted to add a Slider and tell him to hide all bars in my vbar plot which are lower than the value of the slider.

```
    current = df[(df['ID'] > num_tokens.value[0])].dropna()
source.data = {
    'ID': current.ID
}
```

I tried to create a variable 'current' and assign it to the 'ID' column so that the plot can update the plot. But I always get a TypeError: Int is not subscriptable. How can I make my slider widget make work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a *Bokeh server application*? Or standalone HTML output (i.e. from `show`)? Do you want the range to update when the bars get hidden? Or there just to be empty space?

Comment: It is a local bokeh server application. I want the source itself to be untouched and just hide the bars which are lower then my slider value. My dataframe is very big and I want to filter it if necessary, e.g. "show me all bars which y axis value is greater then the value my slider holds". Sry if I can´t explain it better I hope this is enough to understand for you what I am trying to do.

Comment: What about the range? Do you want the range start to adjust so with the slider so that there is never empty space? Or do you want hidden bars to leave empty space (because the range start stays fixed)

Comment: The idea was that the slider holds the value 0 in the beginning so that when you start the application all bars are shown. When you raise the value of the slider the bars with lower y-values should be hidden. The empty spaces between the remaining bars can stay as they are. I don´t want to move them together. So, in fact they just have to get invisible and don´t need to be removed or so.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if we must close this issue or not but I would sugget using a customJS callback:

Create initially a source and a render_soruce from df

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
renderer_source = ColumnDataSource(df)
```

Then define your callback and your slider

```
code = """
    var slider_value= cb_obj.value; //cb_obj is your slider widget
    var data=source.data;
    var data_id = data['ID']; 

    var data_x=data['x'];
    var data_y=data['y'];

    var render_x=render['x'];
    var render_y=render['y'];

    var x = [];
    var y = [];

    render_x=[];
    render_y=[];

for (var i=0;i<data_id.length; i++){

        if (data_id[i]== slider_valuer) {
          x.push(data_x[i]);
          y.push(data_y[i]);

    }

    renderer_source.data['x']=x;
    renderer_source.data['y']=y;

    renderer_source.change.emit();
"""

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, renderer_source=renderer_source), code=code)


slider = Slider(start=0, end=(max_value_o_slider), value=1, step=1, title="Frame")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

And identify `source=renderer_source` in your plot

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with almost no JavaScript using a view:

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, CustomJSFilter, Slider, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 5
x = list(range(1, N + 1))
top = list(range(1, N + 1))

# Specifying manual ranges to prevent range changes when some bars are hidden.
p = figure(x_range=(0, N + 1), y_range=(0, N + 1))

ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, top=top))

s = Slider(start=0, end=N, value=0)

# Making sure that everything that depends on the `ds`
# is notified when the slider value is changed.
s.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(args=dict(ds=ds),
                                 code="ds.change.emit();"))

view = CDSView(source=ds,
               filters=[CustomJSFilter(args=dict(ds=ds, slider=s),
                                       code="return ds.data['top'].map((top) => top > slider.value);")])

p.vbar(x='x', width=0.7, top='top', bottom=0, source=ds, view=view)

curdoc().add_root(column(p, s))
```